# Почему создаются объекты с одинаковыми параметрами

Tags: c#, ооп

Здравствуйте
У меня в программе есть 4 класса:

Базовый Figure:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;

namespace FIGURES_V2
{
class Figure : IComparable<Figure> 
{
    public virtual double getPerimeter()
    {return 0;  }
    public int CompareTo(Figure f)
    {
        return this.Perimeter.CompareTo(f.Perimeter);
    }
    public static int X;
    public static int Y;
    public static int Z;
    public static double SideSize;
    public double Perimeter;
    public  int[] Xcoord = new int[8];
    public  int[] Ycoord = new int[8];
    public  int[] Zcoord = new int[8];
    public string Name;
}
}
```

И производные, Round:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FIGURES_V2
{
class Round : Figure
{
    //public static int X;
    //public static int Y;
    //public static double SideSize;
    //public static double Perimeter;
    //public static int[] Xcoord = new int[4];
    //public static int[] Ycoord = new int[4];
    //public string Name;

  public override   double getPerimeter()
    { return SideSize * Math.PI; }

     void getCoords()
    {
        Xcoord[0] = X;
        Ycoord[0] = Y + (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);

        Xcoord[1] = X + (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);
        Ycoord[1] = Y;

        Xcoord[2] = X;
        Ycoord[2] = Y - (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);

        Xcoord[3] = X - (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);
        Ycoord[3] = Y;
    }

    public Round(int sideSize, int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        SideSize = sideSize;
        //getPerimeter();
        getCoords();
    }
 }
 }
```

Cube:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FIGURES_V2
{
class Cube : Figure
{
    //public static int X;
    //public static int Y;
    //public static int Z;
    //public static double SideSize;
    //public static double Perimeter;
    //public static int[] Xcoord = new int[8];
    //public static int[] Ycoord = new int[8];
    //public static int[] Zcoord = new int[8];
    //public string Name;

    public override double getPerimeter()
    { return SideSize * 8; }


     void getCoords()
    {
        Xcoord[0] = X - (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);
        Ycoord[0] = Y + (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);
        Zcoord[0] = Z - (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);

        Xcoord[1] = X + (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);
        Ycoord[1] = Y + (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);
        Zcoord[1] = Z - (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);

        Xcoord[2] = X + (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);
        Ycoord[2] = Y - (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);
        Zcoord[2] = Z - (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);

        Xcoord[3] = X - (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);
        Ycoord[3] = Y - (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);
        Zcoord[3] = Z - (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);

        Xcoord[4] = X - (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);
        Ycoord[4] = Y + (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);
        Zcoord[4] = Z + (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);

        Xcoord[5] = X + (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);
        Ycoord[5] = Y + (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);
        Zcoord[5] = Z + (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);

        Xcoord[6] = X + (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);
        Ycoord[6] = Y - (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);
        Zcoord[6] = Z + (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);

        Xcoord[7] = X - (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);
        Ycoord[7] = Y - (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);
        Zcoord[7] = Z + (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);
    }


    public Cube(int sideSize, int x, int y, int z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
        SideSize = sideSize;
        getPerimeter();
        getCoords();
    }
}
}
```

И Line:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FIGURES_V2
{
class Line : Figure
{
    //public static int X;
    //public static int Y;
    //public static double SideSize;
    //public static double Perimeter;
    //public static int[] Xcoord = new int[4];
    //public static int[] Ycoord = new int[4];
    //public string Name;

    public override double getPerimeter()
    { return SideSize; }

     void getCoords()
    {
        Xcoord[0] = X - (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);
        Ycoord[0] = Y;

        Xcoord[1] = X + (Convert.ToInt32(SideSize) / 2);
        Ycoord[1] = Y;
    }


    public Line(int sideSize, int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        SideSize = sideSize;
        //getPerimeter();
        getCoords();
    }
}
}
```

В основной программе при чтении с файла в цикле должны создаваться объекты с разными параметрами.

Содержимое файла:

```
round 10 2 3 round 5 4 6 round 3 5 -1 cube 4 -3 -2 3 cube 3 3 5 -2 cube 7 6 8 9 line 1 1 2 line 6 7 4 line 19 4 9
```

Сама программа:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

namespace FIGURES_V2
{
class Program : IEnumerable
{

        static Figure[] arr = new Figure[0];

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("File.txt");
        string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string[] figuresParam = text.Split(' ');

        List<Round> rounds = new List<Round>();
        List<Cube> cubes = new List<Cube>();
        List<Line> lines = new List<Line>();

        for (int i = 0, j = 0, c = 0, l = 0, r = 0; i < figuresParam.Length; i += 4, j += 1)
        {
            if (figuresParam[i] == "round")
            {
                rounds.Add(new Round(Convert.ToInt32(figuresParam[i + 1]), Convert.ToInt32(figuresParam[i + 2]), Convert.ToInt32(figuresParam[i + 3])));
                rounds[r].Name = "round";
                r++;
            }

            if (figuresParam[i] == "cube")
            {
                cubes.Add(new Cube(Convert.ToInt32(figuresParam[i + 1]), Convert.ToInt32(figuresParam[i + 2]), Convert.ToInt32(figuresParam[i + 3]), Convert.ToInt32(figuresParam[i + 4])));
                cubes[c].Name = "cube";
                c++;
                i++;
            }

            if (figuresParam[i] == "line")
            {
                lines.Add(new Line(Convert.ToInt32(figuresParam[i + 1]), Convert.ToInt32(figuresParam[i + 2]), Convert.ToInt32(figuresParam[i + 3])));
                lines[l].Name = "line";
                l++;
            }

        }
```

В итоге же получается вот это(выводится тип фигуры и периметр):
[image: two muppets]
Тобишь создается по 3 идентичных объекта каждого класса в то время как исходные данные для каждого объекта различаются друг от друга.

Почему так получается и как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю проблема в том, что это статическое поле

```
 public static double SideSize;
```

А вычисление периметра в наследниках происходит как–то так:

```
public override double getPerimeter()
{ return SideSize * 8; }
```

Comment: спасибо, заработало)
а я 2 часа пытался выловить ошибку в классе наследнике, совсем не заглядывая в родительский